# erlang; outsmarting compiler with memoization?

Tags: erlang

The following is my solution to Project Euler 14, which works (in 18 s):

```
%Which starting number, under one million, produces the longest Collartz chain?
-module(soln14).
-export([solve/0]).

collatz(L) ->
    [H|T] = L,
    F = erlang:get({'collatz', H}),
    case is_list(F) of 
        true ->
            R = lists:append(F, T);
        false ->
            if H == 1 ->
                R = L;
            true ->  
                if H rem 2 == 0 -> 
                    R = collatz([H div 2 | L]);
                true ->
                    R = collatz([3*H+1 | L])
                end
            end,
        erlang:put({'collatz', lists:last(L)}, R),
        R
    end.


dosolve(N, Max, MaxN, TheList) ->
    if N == 1000000 -> MaxN;
    true ->
        L = collatz([N]),
        M = length(L),
        if M > Max -> dosolve(N+1, M, N, L);
        true -> 
            dosolve(N+1, Max, MaxN, TheList)
        end
    end.

solve() ->
    {Megass, Ss, Micros} = erlang:timestamp(),
     S =     dosolve(1, -1, 1, []),
    {Megase, Se, Microe} = erlang:timestamp(),
    {Megase-Megass, Se-Ss, Microe-Micros, S}.
```

However, the compiler complains:

```
8> c(soln14).
soln14.erl:20: Warning: variable 'R' is unused
{ok,soln14}
9> soln14:solve().
{0,18,-386776,837799}
```

Is this a compiler scoping error, or do I have a legit bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a compiler error, just a warning that in the true case of "case is_list(F) of", the bindning of R to the result of lists:append() is pointless, since this value of R will not be used after that point, just returned immediately. I'll leave it to you to figure out if that's a bug or not. It may be that you are fooled by your indentation. The lines "erlang:put(...)," and "R" are both still within the "false" case of "case is_list(F) of", and should be deeper indented to reflect this.

Comment: The "put" block indeed belonged outside of that block.

Answer (score 0):

The error message and the code are not "synchronized". with the version you give, the warning is on line 10: `R = lists:append(F, T);`.
What it means is that you bind the result of the lists:append/2 call to R and that you don't use it later in the true statement.

this is not the case in the false statement since you use R in the function erlang:put/2.

You could write the code this way:

```
%Which starting number, under one million, produces the longest Collartz chain?
-module(soln14).
-export([solve/0,dosolve/4]).

collatz(L) ->
    [H|T] = L,
    F = erlang:get({'collatz', H}),
    case is_list(F) of 
        true ->
            lists:append(F, T);
        false ->
            R = if H == 1 ->
                L;
            true ->  
                if H rem 2 == 0 -> 
                    collatz([H div 2 | L]);
                true ->
                    collatz([3*H+1 | L])
                end
            end,
            erlang:put({'collatz', lists:last(L)}, R),
            R
    end.

dosolve(N, Max, MaxN, TheList) ->
    if N == 1000000 -> MaxN;
    true ->
        L = collatz([N]),
        M = length(L),
        if M > Max -> dosolve(N+1, M, N, L);
        true -> 
            dosolve(N+1, Max, MaxN, TheList)
        end
    end.

solve() ->
     timer:tc(?MODULE,dosolve,[1, -1, 1, []]).
```

**Warning** the code uses a huge amount of memory, collatz is not tail recursive, and it seems that there is some garbage collecting witch is not done.

Comment: thanks for the comments! Can you add to the tail recursive bit? The memory is by design; it trades space for time using memoization.